# SQL Query from multiple text inputs

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to collect info from four separate text fields and generate queries in the backend to display the results. I have tried many solutions already suggested on here but I keep getting duplicate results. 
I have it working with one query:

```
<?php    
$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE booktitle LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']) . "%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Error in query");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo $row[12]; ?>" width="112px" height="150px" />
<?php
echo "<b>Title: </b>" . $row[1] . "<br />";
echo "<b>Author: </b>" . $row[2] . "<br />";
echo "<b>Price:</b> &pound;" . $row[9] . "<br />";
echo "<b>Description:</b> " . substr($row[3],0,320) . "...<br /><hr>";
}
```

But I also need to incorporate results from the other 3 somehow??

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE author LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']) . "%'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['isbn']) . "%'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE description LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']) . "%'";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an OR statement with the LIKE keyword to search all of these at the same time.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE booktitle LIKE '%" . $title . "%' OR author LIKE'%" . $author . "%' OR isbn LIKE '%" . $isbn . "%' OR description LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%';
```

If the variables are empty then you will have `WHERE booktitle LIKE '%%'`, which returns all rows. You will need to build the query based on the input.

```
// Determine the WHEREs to use
$where = array();
if ( ! empty($title))
    $where[] = "booktitle LIKE '%" . $title . "%'";
if ( ! empty($author))
    $where[] = "author LIKE '%" . $author . "%'";
if ( ! empty($isbn))
    $where[] = "isbn LIKE '%" . $isbn . "%'";
if ( ! empty($description))
    $where[] = "description LIKE '%" . $description . "%'";

// Build the query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM book';
if ( ! empty($where))
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $where);
```

*Note: I have omitted escaping the input for readability.*

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help. But the results are not being filtered, all results from the database are appearing on the search results page. Will I have to do the queries separately and introduce if statements?

Comment: Is $title, $author, $isbn, or $description an empty string? If it is you will be searching for '%%' which will return all records. You should build the query dynamically, adding each piece if the search term exists.

Comment: Yeah the variables will be an empty string sometimes. How would I go about building it dynamically? Sorry I don't have a lot of experience with this.

Comment: That was a massive help, Thank-you so much.

Comment: Glad to help. Remember to accept the answer that most accurately addressed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");

$book_title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
$isbn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['isbn']);
$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE booktitle LIKE '%{$book_title}' OR author LIKE'%" .     $author . "%'
OR isbn LIKE '%" . $isbn . "%' OR description LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

 while($row = $result->fetch_array()):?>
<img src="<?=$row['image_column_name']; ?>" width="112px" height="150px" />
    <b>Title:</b> <?=$row['title_column_name']; ?> <br>
    <b>Author:</b> <?=$row['author_column_name']; ?> <br>
    <b>Price:</b> <?=$row['price_column_name']; ?> <br>
    <b>Description:</b> <?=substr($row['desc_column_name'],0,320)?>
<hr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help me. I'm now getting an error "unexpected end of file". Is something not closed? I can't find it :/

Comment: forgot to space the last line: <?php endwhile; ?>, its in the code now

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. However, it's displaying all results.